# sql: update a given field in all tables instead of just one table

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, openbsd

As per another question, *[sql: update a column if another column poses a conflict in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192388/sql-update-a-column-if-another-column-poses-a-conflict-in-namespace)*, we know that the following could be used to ensure that a set of 10000 unique package names and 100 categories, having 15000 unique combinations (thus table entries in table `categories`), could be updated to ensure that the two namespaces don't collide with one another (affecting about 10 entries in total):

```
UPDATE categories
SET fullpkgpath = fullpkgpath || ',pkg'
WHERE fullpkgpath IN (SELECT value
                      FROM categories)
```

However, the `fullpkgpath` field also repeats in other tables within my sqlite3 database, [as per the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990277/list-tables-and-fields-of-openbsd-databases-sqlports-sqlite3-database/14990280#14990280).

- Is there a way to have the above `UPDATE` statement applied to all other tables within a given sqlite3 database with the same `fullpkgpath` field, without having to manually specify any such extra tables?

  - If the answer to be above is, "*no*", then how would I manually specify which other tables I want the statement applied to?  Consider that only the `categories` table has the categories that could be directly compared with names of packages (to be fair, the `ports` table also has a `categories` field, but it has all the categories of a given port jammed into one field (space separated), as opposed to separate table entries as is the case in the `categories` table).

Comment: The outer query and the subquery are independent.

Comment: @CL., oh, so, I'd have a separate `update` entry, mentioning every table?  OK, that makes sense, now that you mention it; but it'd still be interesting if there's a shortcut for this.

Comment: Normalize your schema?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, please elaborate.

Comment: You have `fullpkgpath` in 18 different tables. To change a single path, you have to make 18 updates. Instead, you could add a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) `path_id` to your `paths` table. `path_id` is just a number generated by the database engine that has nothing to do with your application data. Instead of referencing `fullpkgpath` in your other tables, you reference `path_id`. To change a single `fullpkgpath`, you now only have to make one update.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I think that would make it more complex -- you'd then need to keep mapping and remapping the keys all the time.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by mapping keys. It is more complex, but you don't have to worry about updating redundant data in all of your tables.