# in-memory-only modifications to an SQLite database

Tags: perl, sqlite, sqltransaction

[I'm using perl](https://github.com/cnst/ports-readmes/blob/master/files/make-readmes) with an externally supplied sqlite database to pre-generate about 9k pages for a statically-served website.

[I have some algorithmic improvements to the original data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192388/sql-update-a-column-if-another-column-poses-a-conflict-in-namespace), but for consistency sake, I think it'll make more sense if my scripts leave the original database alone, and modify the data only in memory (if needed, even the whole database should fit into RAM without any issues), prior to generating the web-pages.

How do I do this?

I smell that I could benefit from some kind of an SQL transaction feature here (which should be abandoned after my scripts are done), is that correct?  Does it sound like a good idea, given the constraint of wanting to keep the original database file unmodified?  (E.g., where and how the data from ongoing transactions is stored when using SQLite from Perl?)  Any other way to accomplish what I need?  (I'm perl and sql novice -- looking for annotated code samples.)

I guess as a last resort I could always make a copy of the database file within the filesystem, but that would seem like an ugly and inefficient solution.

Comment: Most databases allow one to create temporary tables. Don't know about SQLite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use the [SQLite backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to load your database into memory.
You'd likely open `:memory:` (or `""` if you want a temporary, file backed DB), and then call [`sqlite_backup_from_file`](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#$dbh->sqlite_backup_from_file(_$filename_)) to load the database in one shot.

e.g. (untested)

```
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:", '', '', {});
$db->sqlite_backup_from_file($ENV{DATABASE});
#Database should be loaded into the current memory DB at this point.
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I might be looking for; it'd be cool if you supply the two lines of code to make it work -- as I said, I'm a perl novice. :-)

Comment: Awesome!  I'll try it out later on, and will report the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a RAM disk and put the database path on that. The details will depend on your OS.